# SUM selected rows in various sheets, but number of sheets can increment overtime

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Let's imagine we have an unknown number of sheets like Employe1, Employe2, Employe3 that increments over time. So in the future, there will be an Employee4, Employee5, etc sheet. All of them have the exact same columns and rows. My app is making them when I add a new employee. What I need to do is sum all of the values in an already existing sheet Reports which has the same structure as the employee sheets have.

So when a new Employee X sheet is created I need to take that into account and calculate the value in the Reports sheet.
Can that somehow be automated?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Unless you want to do this through the API, try [/r/excel](https://reddit.com/r/excel) -- Sheets' formula syntax is compatible with Excel.

Comment: It is for a React project after all, so API is not a problem. 
How would you go about it?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you sum the entire column or is are there other numbers above/below the range you're concerned with?

Comment: Multiple columns and rows ačč with unique values.
So what's in A2 of Sheet1 needs to be summed with A2 in Sheet2, and the result stored in A2 Sheet3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Google app scripts I managed to achieve what was necessary.

```
function SUMALLSHEETS(range, excluded) {
    try {
        var sum = 0,
            ex = (excluded) ? Trim(excluded.split()) : false;
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
            .getSheets()
            .forEach(function (s) {
                if (ex && ex.indexOf(s.getName()) === -1 || !ex) {
                    s.getRange(range)
                        .getValues()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return a.concat(b);
                        })
                        .forEach(function (v) {
                            sum += (!isNaN(parseFloat(v) && isFinite(v))) ? v : 0;
                        });
                };
            });
        return sum;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e.message;
    }
}

function Trim(v) {
    v = (v === null || typeof v == 'undefined') ? '' : v.toString();
    return v.replace(/^\s\s*/, "")
        .replace(/\s\s*$/, "");
}
```